# Runnig a database script after submitting a form with a checkbox in Laravel blade

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a case in my **Laravel** application in which the following flow has to 
 occur :

1. User adds a new item in a form.
2. The form is submitted.
3. An SQL script in the database is run.

How can I trigger this action?

Comment: You'll need to watch more video tutorials on laracasts or youtube.

Comment: what does the script do?

Comment: @Makdous this script is supposed to set a boolean value to true (or false, if the checkbox is not ticked)

Comment: Why would you not just run this from the controller method which handles the form submission?